# Laravel Middleware doesn't work properly for Role Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I have a role middleware. when i pass to role from my controller as a string it's work properly but when pass as an array it's not working. This way middleware work properly.
`$this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author')->except(['userEdit','roleEdit','permissionEdit','userUpdate']);`

But when I change like this, it's not working.

`$this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author')->except(['userEdit','roleEdit','permissionEdit','userUpdate']);`

Here, is my middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$role)
{

    $roles=is_array($role)? $role: explode('|', $role);
    //dd($roles);

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Does it have something to do with how you `explode` your variable? Take a look at `User|Admin|Author` vs `User,Admin,Author`; `explode("|", $role);` will work for one of those, but not the other.

Comment: can you give it as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author')->except(['userEdit','roleEdit','permissionEdit','userUpdate']);
}
```

your middleware

read here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list about the ...$

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    // $roles is array('User', 'Admin', 'Author')
    // 0 => 'User',
    // 1 => 'Admin',
    // 2 => 'Author'

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```